# How to detect emit in another contract using hardhat?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, hardhat, openzeppelin

I'm trying to replicate `expectEvent.inTransaction()` from `@openzeppelin/test-helpers` for hardhat.

**The scenario:** `token` is transfering from `owner` to `receiverContract`. I want to check that receiverContract emitted a `Received` event.

The transaction looks like this and is initiated by the owner.

```js
const tx = await token.transferFrom(
  owner.address, // <- From this wallet
  receiverContract.address, // <- To this contract
  tokenId,
  {
    from: owner.address,
  }
);
```

This test works showing the token emitted a `Transfer` event.

```js
await expect(tx)
  .to.emit(this.token, "Transfer")
  .withArgs(owner.address, receiverContract.address, tokenId);
```

But I want to write something like this...

```js
await expect(tx) // <- Not sure what to put here
  .to.emit(receiverContract, "Received") // <- This may also be off
  .withArgs(token, owner.address, tokenId, null);
```

Or alternatively, I can look through the receiver's receipt object but I'm not sure how to get that either... normally it's via...

```js
const tx = await token.transferFrom(owner.address, receiverContract.address, tokenId, {from: owner.address});
const receipt = await tx.wait();
console.log("receipt", receipt); // <- This will show an events array 
// which I can check. But how do I get this same receipt object for
// the receiverContract
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each contract can be viewed via `console.log(receiverContract)`... so I eventually navigated to the event object inside the contract. Here is a snippet of the contract when logged...

```js
{
  interface: Interface {
    fragments: [ [ConstructorFragment], [EventFragment], [FunctionFragment] ],
    _abiCoder: AbiCoder { coerceFunc: null },
    functions: {
      'onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)': [FunctionFragment]
    },
    errors: {},
    events: { // <- This is what we're looking for
      'Received(address,address,uint256,bytes,uint256)': [EventFragment {
    name: 'Received',
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [ [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType] ],
    type: 'event',
    _isFragment: true
  }],
  // ...
}
```

Running `console.log(receiverContract.interface.events)` gives you this nested object

```js
  'Received(address,address,uint256,bytes,uint256)',
  EventFragment {
    name: 'Received', // <- This is the event name
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [ [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType] ],
    type: 'event',
    _isFragment: true
  }
```

So in order to look for and test that the event emitted, this works

```js
expect(
  Object.entries(receiverContract.interface.events).some(
    ([k, v]: any) => v.name === "Received"
  )
).to.be.equal(true);
```